# How to check for empty td cells (data input is a string) using javascript

Tags: javascript, replace

this is my first post so go easy on me :D

Basically i've got a table that is front end editable by using a wordpress plugin. There data inputed in the table will have to be shown as a sort of heatmap - the values in it will be represented by a different color for a different value.

I really think the table itself is not important but the next part is

```
   function showTableData() {

var myTab = document.getElementById('table_1');
var tabledata="";


for (i = 1; i < myTab.rows.length; i++) {


    var objCells = myTab.rows.item(i).cells;


    for (var j = 0; j < objCells.length; j++) {

        tabledata=tabledata+''+"<div class='test' style='display:inline'>"+objCells.item(j).innerHTML+"</div>";
        if(j==31) 
        {
        tabledata=tabledata+''+"<div class='test' style='display:inline'>"+objCells.item(j).innerHTML+"</div><br>"; 
        }


    }
    document.getElementById('tabledata').innerHTML=tabledata;


}

}
```

I've used this code above to show the values of the table on the website
for the beginning the table will be max 30x30, if added if(j==31) for it to add a break ( to make it look table-ish on the web) and added a div for every value of the table so in the future i will be able to change the backgroud according to the value of it.

Now what i need is if the field in the table is blank at the place where it writes down table values it should say 0 as for now it doesnt say anything

!https://gyazo.com/948f6839808567d838ff026ed7155e98

Any help would be appreciated :D

```
       edit: forgot to say i tried using 

      if(tabledata==='')
   {
    tabledata=tabledata+''+"<div class='test' style='display:inline'>"+objCells.item(j).innerHTML+'0'+"</div>"; 
    }
```

EDIT: and in the if i tried placing objcells==='' and objCells.item(j).innerHTML==='' and tabledata+objCells.item(j).innerHTML==='0'

but the only thing i achieve is to output a 0 on every value (if it is value 2 it would write it as 02 etc)

Thank you again and feel free to correct me if im not really formatting my questions correctly :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out, i just changed the if statements cuz i've realised what i've been doing was rather stupid

```
        function showTableData() {

var myTab = document.getElementById('table_1');
var tabledata="";


for (i = 1; i < myTab.rows.length; i++) {


    var objCells = myTab.rows.item(i).cells;

    for (var j = 0; j < objCells.length; j++) {


        if(j==29) 
        {

        tabledata=tabledata+''+"<div class='test' style='display:inline'>"+objCells.item(j).innerHTML+"</div><br>"; 

        }
        else if(objCells.item(j).innerHTML=='' )
        {
         tabledata=tabledata+''+"<div class='test' style='display:inline'>"+objCells.item(j).innerHTML+'0'+"</div>";    
        }

        else tabledata=tabledata+''+"<div class='test' style='display:inline'>"+objCells.item(j).innerHTML+"</div>";



    }

    document.getElementById('tabledata').innerHTML=tabledata;


}

}
```

now its just not placing a 0 if a last element in a row is empty but hopefully i'll figure that out